# ms access: pop up form is cut off in form view

Tags: ms-access, popup, ms-access-forms

I have pop-up form for data entry. The form has a subform on it that is surrounded by blank cells of equal sizes similar to padding. (Why not use padding instead? Because I want to add functionality to those cells later on). When I view the form in form view (opening it), part of the right hand side is cut off such that it no longer looks like equally sized padding.

What's weird is that if I look at the form in layout view, the form is not cut off. And if I then open the form FROM Layout view, the form is also not cut off. But if I open the form in any other way (from a button, vba, right click open from navigator etc.), it is being cut off every time.

Does anybody know why this might be happening and how I might fix it?

---

***Form being cut off***

[image: Form being cut off on the right]

***Form not cut off in layout view***

[image: Form displaying correctly in layout view]

***Form not cut off when opened FROM layout view***

[image: Form displaying correctly when opened FROM layout view]

Comment: Make sure that the `AutoResize` property of the form is set to Yes. Then popup width will be form (sections) width.

Comment: 'AutoResize' is on. And apparently it works, but only if I open the form after viewing it in Layout view. Opening it any other way does not.

Comment: Try to leave a bit more space left/right, especially to the right. From my experience, Access crops the forms a bit more that what it should.

Comment: That works, but I'd rather be able to have the form be set to exactly the size of it's contents and not have to guess if it looks flush or not when adjusting the size in design view. It's not very precise. Is there no better way?

Comment: Nope, nothing that I'm aware of. Nice design by the way.

Comment: Thx! Maybe there is a way to achieve this in vba idk. I'll leave the question up for a while longer, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue occurs when working in access with a higher display resolution than 1920x1080. 3440x1440 in my case.

The only solutions I have found is what you described by opening the form in layout view then switching to form view then save the form.

Only other option is changing display resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a "work around" on this same subject, hopefully it may help in certain cases where the issue is NOT due to Form Sizing through VBA code, which is determined to be the cause inadvertently.

My scenario:

Popup forms, set to auto center, auto resize, fit to screen = truncated, or overcropped form (and DESPITE my own VBA sizing code, which doesn't seemingly "take" or correct the issue).

I usually/often have the scrollbars property set to "neither", so I tried setting "both" on, and the popup form is no longer truncated. I then tried with ONLY the "Horizonal" bar set to on, and it still worked correctly. I then turned both BACK OFF and the form still sized correctly. I saved the form and it appears to have retained the "sizing" properly going forward.

It's as if when you turn these options to neither, the space normally occupied by those scrollbars is "taken off" the borders of the form "again" so maybe toggling that property to both/vertical only/horizontal only/neither "resets" and corrects it. Just a guess.

Hope this helps, spread the word of this little "work around."

O.W. Khan